Как можно получить доступ к камере телефона через приложения написанное на С++?
Например сделать простую программу в которой будет кнопка START по центру и при её нажатие получить доступ к камере телефона. Как можно это сделать ?

Первая же ссылка в google: https://habr.com/ru/articles/544614/

@Chorkov - обалденно, не хотите свой комментарий переделать в полноценный ответ?

@S.H.  Дать просто ссылку - это не релевантный ответ.  А выделить из статьи суть - потребует гораздо более серьезного погружения в проблему.
